# Messenger Bot Webview not closing on IOS

Tags: bots, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a webview in my bot.
I have the following JS code to close it:

```
complete: function (data) {
                    MessengerExtensions.requestCloseBrowser(function success() {
                        }, function error(err) {
                            window.close()
                        });
                    console.log("post success");
                }
```

The webview is being closed on **ANDROID** and **WEB** But **NOT** on **IOS**.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So apparently my problem was a mistake which led to a misunderstanding of the problem.

I didn't add `messenger_extensions: true` and didn't **whitelist** my domain. Due to that the `MessengerExtensions` call failed, and always got to the fallback which was `window.close()` - which works on WEB and Android, but not on IOS - hence I thought that all works but IOS.

After adding `messenger_extensions: true` and **whitelisting** the domain all worked out.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for related bugs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs), i searched for a one related to your issue but there is none.